# Can steering wheel angle/torque sensor fit to a car that had it optional?

Tags: sensor, steering-wheel, corsa, esp-esc, punto

I need to read steering angle from a car for research purposes. My question is - can I fit a steering wheel angle/torque sensor to a particular car that itself has no ESP/ESC (Electronic Stability Program/Control) built in but where ESP was sold as an option for that model? I mean, there should be space to accommodate such sensor even without the car needing to have ESP, right? I don't need the ESP functionality, I just need to fit the sensor and read values from it. It is cheaper for me to get a car without ESP and add the sensor to it only.

The cars of interest are following (both had optional ESP):

- Opel/Vauxhall Corsa C
- Fiat Punto Mk2 (model 188)

My guess would be this should be possible (since in factory all chassis are same and they either mount the SAS sensor or not), but I would rather have something confirming this. Thanks!

Comment: I would think that most manufacturers would find it cheaper to design parts one way and leave a gap where the optional sensor would fit.  I would start the journey pricing out the steering wheel sensor component part for the vehicles you are interested it.  You should be able to tell from that how the interface works.

Comment: It sounds like you're wanting to plug the sensor into the factory harness and read data straight from the OBD port or CAN BUS, you'll have problems I think. Even if the plug is there, the ecu/bcu may not have been programmed for it.

Tip though, the ~2007ish Toyota Yaris steering angle sensor may be the part you want to look at and then process the output via an Arduino or something.

Comment: @AaronLavers I will read the data directly without plugging the SAS into ECU.

Comment: @Kozuch ah awesome! Yeah then definitely have a look at the Yaris EPS angle sensor, we wired one into a mates KP61 Starlet in order to set up monitoring for a homebrew ECU setup. He mentioned to me that working with it was pretty straight forward. I couldn't help with the logic behind it however, sorry.